# Odd bash behaviour with nested variables

Tags: mysql, bash

I like to put my connection and general dump settings into variables and then feed them to `mysqldump` like so:

```
# echo mysqldump ${SRC_SRV} ${SRC_SQL_OPT}
mysqldump -u root -pPass -h host --where="COL > '2016-08-14' AND COL <= '2016-08-15'" --opt --single-transaction --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info dbase table
```

There are my `bash` variables:

```
WHERE="COL > '2016-08-14' AND COL <= '2016-08-15'"
SRC_SQL_OPT="--where=\"${WHERE}\" --opt --single-transaction --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info ${DB} ${TBL}"
```

Note, that when I `echo` - it all seems normal, but if I try to run it in `bash` I get an error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '>' when selecting the database
```

And here's the reason why (`bash -x`):

```
+ mysqldump -u root -pPass -h host '--where="COL' '>' ''\''2016-08-14'\''' AND COL '<=' ''\''2016-08-15'\''"' --opt --single-transaction --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info dbase table
```

Note: now there is a bunch of extra single quotes around the `--where` option... **How**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SRC_SQL_OPT` contains the following string:

```
--where="COL > '2016-08-14' AND COL <= '2016-08-15'" --opt --single-transaction --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info dbase table
```

When expanding that string in `mysqldump ${SRC_SRV} ${SRC_SQL_OPT}`, Bash splits the variables into separate arguments on its [internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).

Since, by default, the field separator is whitespace, `$SRC_SQL_OPT` gets split on *every* occurrence of whitespace—irrespective of whether that space occurred within a quote or not.  One can prevent Bash from splitting variables by quoting them, but since you actually want that variable split elsewhere, you'd either need to:

- separate out the where part (as [@Pianosaurus has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952561)), eg:

  ```
  WHERE="COL > '2016-08-14' AND COL <= '2016-08-15'"
  SRC_SQL_OPT="--opt --single-transaction --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info ${DB} ${TBL}"

  mysqldump $SRC_SRV --where="$WHERE" $SRC_SQL_OPT
  ```
- use a different internal field separator, eg:

  ```
  WHERE="COL > '2016-08-14' AND COL <= '2016-08-15'"
  SRC_SRV="-u;root;-pPass;-h;host"
  SRC_SQL_OPT="--where=\"$WHERE\";--opt;--single-transaction;--skip-triggers;--no-create-db;--no-create-info;$DB;$TBL"

  IFS=';' mysqldump $SRC_SRV $SRC_SQL_OPT
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant difference between your first command, and the version you are probably using with bash variables.

When you run a command such as the one in your first code block, the double quotes are interpreted by bash itself, and the contents sent to the command as a single argument.

In your bash variables, you are explicitly inserting a literal quote. The only way of making bash parse this the way you want, is to `eval` the command, since it contains both spaces inside quotes and outside them.

The cleanest way to do this in bash, is to avoid such nested variables in commands. In your case, don't make `SRC_SQL_OPT` before running the command. Or at least, don't include the `--where`-part.